# How to mirror a git repository to the specific branch of another?

Tags: git, github

Suppose that one is involved in a Github-hosted project, he start his work by firstly forking the repository from its original place, and then clone the forked repository to the local machine and commit the patches back to this new repository under his own Github acccout. Now, the project wants its contributors to commit their patches to the main repository as different branches.

How to achieve it? 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The project has already made the rules of naming the branches, i.e., to use his/her Github id.

Comment: Why not just keep the forks the way they are? That’s a lot easier to manage…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add all the contributors as—well—contributors to the GitHub project. Then, each developer can work on local branches, and just need to push to the properly named branches when pushing…

```
git checkout -b poke-some-feature
# do work
git push origin poke-some-feature
```